# Handle external SVG path hover/clicked

Tags: reactjs, svg, mouseclick-event, mousehover

My problem is that i have an svg file with 5 big paths so i import the svg and add it into an iframe,

```
 return (
            <div className='mapContainer'>
                <iframe src={map} title="map" width="400" height="300" frameBorder="none"/>
            </div>
    );
```

is there any way i can get the hover or (and) click event on each path?

Comment: Sure, put the code for that in the svg file.

Comment: and how can I handle this inside the react native function?

Comment: Why would you need to?

Comment: so I want to load an SVG file to my website and make it interactive so when someone hovers over a path would do something or(and) when someone click the specific path would do something else

Comment: sure but why don't you like my suggestion?

Comment: I want to find a way to do that outside of the SVG file ... if there is no way I can do that then yes I will put the code inside it

Comment: You can do it but it's harder. Easier to do it inside the file. You can always call methods in the iframe from the parent document if you need to.